# jquery ui autocomplete - suggestions show only once on BB5

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jqueryui autocomplete and it works great on desktop and most of the mobile devices - ipad, iphone ,etc. However on blackberry 5, when I type in pis for the first time it shows the suggestions list immediately. when I break see the list and type in additional letter, I dont see the suggestions anymore. I change the text, do whatever and no suggestions until I reload the page and it repeats the same issue again. Should I do anything different with BB5? Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue.  On BB devices the device autocomplete seems to be conflicting with jquery autocomplete functionality.  Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery UI are you using?  Blackberry 5 only has [limited support](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/BB_Browser_content_support_by_version_438586_11.jsp) for JavaScript 1.6 and this may be why your implementation is functioning oddly.  It may be that there is nothing you can do to fix it for BB5 users.